# How can I read a specifc column from a text file and calculate the average of this column?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am a little stuck with a java exercise I am currently working on. I have a text file in this format:

Quio Kla,2221,3.6
Wow Pow,3332,9.3
Zou Tou,5556,9.7
Flo Po,8766,8.1
Andy Candy,3339,6.8

I now want to calculate the average of the whole third column, but I have to extract the data first I believe and store it in an array. I was able to read all the data with a buffered reader and print out the entire file in console, but that did not get me closer to get it into an array. Any suggestions on how I can read in a specific column of a text file with a buffered readder into an array would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your text file by using this portion of code:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textfile.txt"));
String read = null;
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splited = read.split(",");
        for (String part : splited) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

And then you'll have all your columns in the array `part`.

Answer (score 0):

It`s definitely not the best solution, but should be sufficient for you

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/file"));
                int numOfColumn = 2;
                String line = "";
                ArrayList<Integer>lines =  new ArrayList<>();
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(Integer.valueOf(line.split(",")[numOfColumn-1]));
                }
                long sum =0L;
                for(int j:lines){
                    sum+=j;
                }
                int avg = (int)sum/lines.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume each data set is separated by newline characters in your text file.

```
ArrayList<Double> thirdColumn = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader in = null;
String line=null;

//initialize your reader here

while ((line = in.readLine())!=null){

    String[] split = line.split(",");

    if (split.length>2)
        thirdColumn.add(Double.parseDouble(split[2]));
}
```

By the end of the while loop, you should have the `thirdColumn` ArrayList ready and populated with the required data.

The assumption is made that your data set has the following standard format.

String,Integer,Double

So naturally a split by a comma should give a String array of length 3, Where the String at index 2 contains your third column data.